# Найти все элементы TextBlock в окне WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Мне нужно пробежаться по всем элементам окна WPF, найти элемент TextBlock и вывести на экран его текст.

Comment: Пробегаться никуда не надо. Надо создать свойство и привязать его к свойству `Text` у  `TextBlock`. Или можно прямо в XAML связать свойства `Text` у `TextBox` и `TextBlock`.

Comment: посмотрите вот здесь: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/415264/178667

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то возможно этот вариант подойдет.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SearchCtl();
    }

    private void SearchCtl()
    {
        foreach( FrameworkElement txt in grid.Children )
        {
            if ( txt is TextBlock )
            {
                TextBlock txtBlock = ( TextBlock ) txt;
                MessageBox.Show( txtBlock.Text );
            }
            else
                continue;
        }
    }
}
```